# Reading and parsing from file in java. How can I get it to read and print the details for lion etc

Tags: java

I am looking for some help with my code. I don't need to know the whole code... just trying to figure out how to read from a file in java. I can get it to read one line, but that's it. Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance. 
Here is the text from the file I am trying to read from...

Details on lions
Details on tigers
Details on bears
Details on giraffes

Animal - Lion

Name: Leo

Age: 5

*****Health concerns: Cut on left front paw

Feeding schedule: Twice daily

Animal - Tiger

Name: Maj

Age: 15

Health concerns: None

Feeding schedule: 3x daily

```
package monitoringsystem;

import java.util.Scanner;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.*;






public class MonitoringSystem {


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 * 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner inFS = null;

    FileInputStream animals = null;
    FileInputStream habitats = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    String monitorChoice = "";
    String animalChoice = "";
    String habitatChoice = "";


    System.out.println("Would you like to monitor an Animal, Habitat, or exit?");
    monitorChoice = scnr.nextLine();


    if (monitorChoice.equals("Animal")) {
        System.out.println("Choose an animal to monitor: Lion, Tiger, Bear, or Giraffe.");

        animals = new FileInputStream("animals.txt");
        animalChoice = scnr.nextLine();

        File file = new File("animals.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

       String currentLine = br.readLine();
        while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (currentLine.contains(animalChoice)) {
                String nameline = br.readLine();
                String ageline = br.readLine();
                String feedline = br.readLine();
                System.out.println(currentLine);
                System.out.println(nameline);
                System.out.println(ageline);
                System.out.println(feedline);
            }
```

Now the only issue I have is getting it to omit the line with the ***** and skip to the feeding line. Again...Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: Don't `return` :)

Comment: delete the `return;` and loop will continue running reading all the lines

Comment: `while ((br.readLine()) != null)` you need to assign that to your `currentLine`, as in `while (currentLine = (br.readLine()) != null) `

Comment: How many rows are there per Animal? 5?

Comment: Yes. There are five

Comment: Ok that works better.... however, if I type in Tiger... it just prints Animal - Tiger

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple program to read from a file formatted as per your example

```
package animals;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Animals {
    public static class Animal {
        private String animalType;
        private String name;
        private String age;
        private String healthConcerns;
        private String feedingSchedule;
        public boolean isComplete() {
            return animalType != null && name != null && age != null && age != null && healthConcerns != null && feedingSchedule != null;
        }
        public void loadFrom(BufferedReader in) throws IOException {

            for(String line; !isComplete() && (line=in.readLine()) != null;) {
                line = line.trim();
                if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                    if (line.startsWith("Animal - ")) {
                        animalType = line.split(" - ")[1];
                    } else if (line.contains(":")) {
                        String[] fields = line.split(":");
                        switch(fields[0]) {
                            case "Feeding schedule":
                                this.feedingSchedule = fields[1].trim();
                                break;
                            case "Age":
                                this.age = fields[1].trim();
                                break;
                            case "Name":
                                this.name = fields[1].trim();
                                break;
                            case "Health concerns":
                            default:
                                this.healthConcerns = fields[1].trim();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                } 
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Animal{" + "animalType=" + animalType + ", name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", healthConcerns=" + healthConcerns + ", feedingSchedule=" + feedingSchedule + '}';
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
        List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList();
        Animal a = null;
        do {
            a = new Animal();
            a.loadFrom(in);
            if (a.isComplete()) {
                animals.add(a);
            }
        } while (a.isComplete());
        for (Animal animal : animals) {
            System.out.println(animal);
        }
    }
}
```

The output, given your input file looks like this:
package animals;

```
Animal{animalType=Lion, name=Leo, age=5, healthConcerns=Cut on left front paw, feedingSchedule=Twice daily}
Animal{animalType=Tiger, name=Maj, age=15, healthConcerns=None, feedingSchedule=3x daily}
```